# Running Steam on the Ubuntu 16.10 desktop

Tags: games, steam

I have ubuntu 16.10 on my desktop. I've downloaded steam on my computer after installing ubuntu 16.10 on my desktop and it wasn't working so my friend used chrome remote desktop to uninstall it but it didn't complete and because it was not working and I tried pressing the uninstall button but it got cancelled and after that my friend did something and steam updates got installed but Steam when it was lauched the first time it said 
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libXrandr.s02
libgobject-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpulse.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
Please help me with this